# Python Concat Two Dictionaries with comma

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have two dicts in python

```
d1={1:2,3:4}
d2={5:6,7:9}
```

How can I combine that to make

```
d2 = {{1:2,3:4}, {5:6,7:9}}
```

Comment: Look into `numpy` (structured arrays, aka record arrays) and use either the `concatenate` or `vstack` function

Comment: To clarify, do you want to combine into one dictionary (i.e.: `d2 = {1:2,3:4,5:6,7:9}`), or make `d2` a dictionary of two dictionaries?

Comment: `d2 = {{1:2,3:4}, {5:6,7:9}}` is not valid Python. Do you mean `d2 = [{1:2,3:4}, {5:6,7:9}]`, `d2 = "{{1:2,3:4}, {5:6,7:9}}"`, `d2 = {9:{1:2,3:4}, 10:{5:6,7:9}}`, what @TheBrofessor said...?

Comment: Does `d3=d1,d2` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amadan has already suggested, you seem to be wanting a list of two items holding d1 and d2. This can be easily created using the following:

```
d1 = {1:2,3:4}
d2 = {5:6,7:9}

mylist = [d1, d2]

print mylist
```

This would display the items as follows:

```
[{1: 2, 3: 4}, {5: 6, 7: 9}]
```

You could then iterate through each dictionary as follows:

```
for d in list_of_d1_d2:
    for k, v in d.items():
        print "{}: {}".format(k,v)
    print
```

This would display:

```
1: 2
3: 4

5: 6
7: 9
```

Tested using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Your request for d2 is not actually a dictionary, but a list. Dictionaries contain key-value pairs. d2 = {{1:2,3:4}, {5:6,7:9}} won't even work I don't think. d2 = [{1:2, 3:4}, {5:6, 7:9}] would likely work, and be easier to pull information from.